How to convert Unix timestamp to zonedDateTime in ECharts?
I'm quite new to ECharts. I'm using it with Grafana.
The source database is InfluxDB and all the measurements are stored in the format: 1720788623000.
I want to make it a readable date for the x-axis in a line graph.
How can this be done?
Formatting to 2024-07-12T14:51:01.339Z would be alright, I know how to go from here.
I tried some thing like utcToZonedTime(), but the required import with the command: import { utcToZonedTime, format } from 'date-fns-tz'; didn't work.
Here I get an error:

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

I didn't find much other solutions, so it might not be possible?

I don't know the details of your setting are and what restrictions you have, however, if you are using javascript, the timestamp can be converted to a Date object using new Date(1720788623000). The Date instance has several formatting methods; the one that produces the string you mentioned is toISOString. So, in vanilla js, new Date(1720788623000).toISOString() returns '2024-07-12T12:50:23.000Z'

If you still want to use date-fns, in a non-module environment you may use scripts with CDN or local sources, as described in the documentation.

Well do I feel stupid!
But you helped me to go in the right direction.
I tried new Date(), but the input of the variable was false.
When using, new Date(1720788623000), I got the result I expected.
This got me thinking that the variable might be interperted as a String.
When converted to a number, it works!
Thank you for your help!
